# Add Rewrite Endpoint to CPT Archive

Tags: rewrite-rules, endpoints

I have a Custom Post Type with a hierarchical taxonomy archive and want to add an endpoint page called "infopage" to each term in the archive.

e.g.

```
domain.com/tax-term-1/infopage
```

or

```
domain.com/tax-term-2/child-term-3/child-term-4/infopage
```

etc.

I don't want to add this as a child term, but rather want it to be a "virtual" page as the contents will be generated dynamically.

Tried something like this but was getting a 404 when accessing the endpoint page (yes, I flushed permalinks):

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'infopage', EP_PAGES );
} );

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    global $wp_query;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_query->query_vars['infopage'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/infopage.php';
    die;
} );
```

Is `add_rewrite_endpoint` not meant to be used with CPTs and custom taxonomies? If not, is there a recommended alternative way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the 404 most likely because your custom *taxonomy* is not assigned to the endpoint mask (`EP_PAGES`) used with your endpoint.

Because [`add_rewrite_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/) does work with custom post types and taxonomies, but **you need to assign the *endpoint mask* to the post type or taxonomy** during registration, via the `ep_mask` key in the `rewrite` argument for [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#arguments) as well as [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#rewrite), like so:

```php
// Add the "infopage" endpoint with the endpoint mask EP_PAGES.
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'infopage', EP_PAGES );

// Register a "foo" post type.
register_post_type( 'foo', array(
    'public'  => true,
    'label'   => 'Foos',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'ep_mask' => EP_PAGES, // assign EP_PAGES to the CPT
        'slug'    => 'foos',
    ),
) );

// Register a hierarchical taxonomy for the "foo" CPT above.
register_taxonomy( 'foo_cpt', 'foo', array(
    'public'       => true,
    'label'        => 'Foo Categories',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite'      => array(
        'ep_mask'      => EP_PAGES, // assign EP_PAGES to the taxonomy
        'hierarchical' => true,     // this one is entirely up to you
    ),
) );
```

So assign the endpoint mask *and then flush the rewrite rules* (simply visit the Permalink Settings admin page), and see if you're still getting the 404.

---

Additionally, if you're unable to change the `register_taxonomy()` or `register_post_type()` code (e.g. because the post type or taxonomy is registered using a 3rd-party plugin), then you could use the [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) or [`register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) hook to modify the taxonomy or post type arguments.

And as for the "recommended alternative", then it would be using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to manually add the rewrite rule for your endpoint, e.g. `add_rewrite_rule( 'foo_cpt/(.+?)/infopage(/(.*))?/?$', 'index.php?foo_cpt=$1&infopage=$3', 'top' )` for the `foo_cpt` taxonomy above. :)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: PS: Sorry, I meant to use `foo_cat` and not `foo_cpt` as the taxonomy slug..